# UK Vehicle Data: Implementation of Price Per Kilo Function

Tags: php, json, wordpress, widget, wordpress-shortcode

I just need to get the widget to show the price per kilo (12p) for scrapping the car and I'd be eternally grateful if somebody could give me a helping hand with this :)

[image]

The data is JSON and it's from UK Vehicle data. I'm trying to implement it in a wordpress widget.

This is the data, which i've been provided:

```
{
  "Request": {
    "ApiKeyId": "6da2f3bb-c911-4adf-9d80-9a09e11f1362",
    "PackageId": "ValuationData",
    "PackageVersion": 2,
    "ResponseVersion": 2
  },
  "Response": {
    "StatusCode": "Success",
    "StatusMessage": "Success",
    "StatusInformation": {},
    "MetaDataForKeys": [
      {
        "Name": "Vrm|Vin",
        "Type": "String",
        "IsMandatory": true
      }
    ],
    "MetaDataForItems": {
      "ExtractNumber": {
        "Name": "ExtractNumber",
        "Type": "String"
      },
      "Mileage": {
        "Name": "Mileage",
        "Type": "String"
      },
      "PlateYear": {
        "Name": "PlateYear",
        "Type": "String"
      },
      "ValuationBook": {
        "Name": "ValuationBook",
        "Type": "String"
      },
      "ValuationList": {
        "Name": "ValuationList",
        "Type": "List"
      },
      "ValuationTime": {
        "Name": "ValuationTime",
        "Type": "System.DateTime"
      },
      "VehicleDescription": {
        "Name": "VehicleDescription",
        "Type": "String"
      },
      "Vrm": {
        "Name": "Vrm",
        "Type": "String"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sandbox JSON connection string

https://uk1.ukvehicledata.co.uk/api/datapackage/BatteryData?v=2&api_nullitems=1&auth_apikey=6da2f3bb-c911-4adf-9d80-9a09e11f1362&key_VRM=KM12AKK

Comment: Well where are you stuck? Did you follow the instructions in the picture? What's the specific problem? Your question is too vague - it's not clear what help is required. "I need" isn't a question and doesn't describe a problem you've encountered while attempting to implement what you want. Bear in mind also, you need to ask an actual programming question - we're not a helpdesk for existing packaged software. Take the [tour] and read [ask] for more guidance

Comment: I'm so sorry about that, i tried to make it clear but because i'm new to all of this, it's difficult. Basically, at the moment, the widget can take a car registration and print the estimated price of scrapping the car but i've been told by UKDV that i can use the json data here to add the functionality to print the price per kilo of scrapping said car: 

The price per kilo is 12p so what code would i enter to work that out based on the weight?

Comment: No problem. But please edit the question to be much more specific about the issue and indicate what you've done so far. Don't add info to the comments where it can get lost. This isn't a discussion forum (again, see the [tour])

Comment: P.s. if you want to know how to make use of some JSON data it would also make sense to show us a sample of the relevant data

Comment: Thank you so much for the responses, i'll edit the question now

Comment: That doesn't provide the info I mentioned

Comment: @ADyson I've updated the question with the data provided, i hope that this explains it well enough now?

Comment: So...what pieces of data are you wanting to extract from that JSON, exactly? I don't see any info in there about prices or weights. It's unclear how you expect to derive a price per kilo from the provided data.

Comment: @ADyson I'm so sorry, i've looked into this further and now have the correct info. Is it best to repost the question entirely or edit the whole thing. I can't tell you how much i appreciate your help buddy

Comment: You should edit it :-)